# Ubuntu 13.10: No ethernet + WiFi on hp mini 1033CL netbook (Marvell + BCM4312)

Tags: wireless, networking, hp, broadcom

I took out my hp mini 1033 CL netbook from its retirement today and installed Ubuntu 13.10 on it to use it during a trip abroad soon.

All seems to be working fine except connecting it to the internet.
The network applet shows the empty triangular icon and clicking on it shows Ethernet Network disconnected. No mention of WiFi either. When connecting an ethernet cable to the router, nothing happens.
The additional drivers window in  'Software & Updates' is empty, although I expected to see at least Broadcom's STA driver.

'lspci' command produced those 2 relevant lines:

> 01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
>
> 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller

Is there a way to install necessary drivers without a connection (through a flash drive)? If so, kindly guide me through the steps in a not so technical manner as I'm still a noob.

Thanks.

EDIT:
As to @chili555 's comment:

> dmesg | grep sky2

results in

```
[    2.713924] sky2: driver version 1.30
[    2.713998] sky2 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.714180] sky2 0000:02:00.0: unsupported chip type 0xff
[    2.714288] sky2: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -95
[    3.176248] Modules linked in: i915(+) ssb sky2 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper wmi drm video(F)
[    3.195068] Modules linked in: i915(+) ssb sky2 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper wmi drm video(F)
```

Comment: Did you check if your post is not a duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33855/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm4312-wireless-card-to-work) page and [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80402/broadcom-bcm4312-not-working) page?

Comment: @mcantsin, yes. However, most solutions either assume a working ethernet connection (through apt-get, synaptic, etc...) or involve very old versions (Ubuntu 10/11) and kernels, so the same packages may not be maintained anymore.

Comment: ouch! - And it's [Ubuntu certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/200912-4896/)

Comment: Isn't that interesting?!

Comment: Yes, almost scary!

Comment: you might want to give your respective [feedback here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+addquestion?field.title=Feedback%20on%20the%20Dell%20Inspiron%201545)

Comment: A great many devices work perfectly well in Ubuntu if proprietary firmware is loaded and therefore are counted as certified. 14e4:4315 is among them.

Answer (score 0):

Your ethernet uses the driver *sky2*. Please hook up the ethernet and see if the driver loads. Open a terminal and run:

```
lsmod
```

Is *sky2* listed? If not, load it:

```
sudo modprobe sky2
```

Was an interface created, ideally eth0?

```
ifconfig
```

Does it connect? If not, let's move on to the wireless and solve the ethernet later. Download this file to your desktop: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/l/linux-firmware-nonfree/linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb  Install it from the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Unload and reload the driver so it sees and uses the new firmware:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should now be working. If so, we'll tackle the ethernet. If not, check for informative messages:

```
dmesg | grep b43
```

Check for informative messages about the ethernet:

```
dmesg | grep sky2
```

Does the error you posted persist if you do:

```
sudo modprobe -r sky2 
sudo modprobe sky2
dmesg | grep sky2
ifconfig  <--no need to post the whole thing; just tell us if eth0 appears
```

Look for dmesg entries later than [3.19..]. Or also:

```
sudo modprobe -r sky2
sudo modprobe sky2 legacy_pme=1
dmesg | grep sky2
ifconfig  <--no need to post the whole thing; just tell us if eth0 appears
```

If either technique helps, we can write a file or two and make it persistent.

If there are still errors, please reboot so we have a clean slate and run:

```
dmesg > sky2.txt
```

Find the text file sky2.txt in your user directory and paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ Give us the link in your reply.

Please be sure your system (i.e. kernel version) is fully updated:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

If a newer linux-image is installed, reboot.

I see the following in your dmesg:

> [    2.827902] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 107 at
>   /build/buildd/linux-3.11.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:1074 assert_pipe+0x82/0xe0 i915 
>   [    2.827913] pipe A assertion failure (expected on, current off) 
>   [    2.827918] Modules linked in: i915(+) **sky2** ssb i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper wmi drm video(F) 
>   [    2.827950]CPU: 1 PID: 107 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: GF       W  3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu

I'm not at all sure it has much or even anything to do with your issue, but I'd research and resolve it. I also notice that your system takes a very long time to boot and seems, if I am reading correctly, to get stuck at:

> [    3.241201] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0
>   on minor 0

This looks like another i915 video issue.

Aside from these observations, I regret I am out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks @chili555,my wireless is now functional. Ethernet still not. sky2 was already listed but ifconfig did not show an eth0 section. Only lo.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Added output to original comment.

Comment: still getting similar error messages and no eth0 in ifconfig.

Comment: here's the link of sky2.txt
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6792537/

Comment: We see: "sky2 0000:02:00.0 eth0: enabling interface" If you click the Network Manager icon and disconnect the wireless, does the ethernet work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It continues to show Ethernet connection disconnected, while the icon never changes to a wired one. Just an empty wifi one.